# Can not clear select option value using Jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax, selectize.js

I am not able to clear the select option value dynamically using Jquery. I am explaining my code below.

**report.php:**

```
    <div class="col-sm-4">
    <select class="form-control selectized" data-live-search="true" name="cmbExamgrp" id="cmbExamgrp" onChange="selectExamType(this.value,'<?=$MY_SESSION_NAME?>')">
    <option value="">Select Exam Group</option>
        </select>
    </div>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-info tooltips" name="btnReset" id="btnReset" title="Reset"><i class="fa fa-filter"></i> Reset</button>
```

Here I have also Reset button to clear the field when clicked on it.

**report.js:**

```
 function selectExamType(grpType,session){
        var data = {
            type:"SELECT_EXAM_TYPE",
            grpType:grpType,
            _s:session
        };
        $.ajax({
            url:"exam_registrant_report_db.php",
            mType:"get",
            data:data,
            success:function(response){         
                var option_arr = new Array();
                var options = "";       
                $('#cmbExamtype').selectize()[0].selectize.destroy();   
                var select = $('#cmbExamtype').selectize(options); 
                var selectize = select[0].selectize;                            
                var res1 = JSON.parse(response);                    
                $.each(res1.aaData,function(i,data){
                    var option_arr = ({value:data.exam_type,text:data.exam_type});
                    selectize.addOption(option_arr);
                    //if(i == 0)
                    //  selectize.setValue(data.exam_type);
                }); 
                var examType = $('#cmbExamtype').val(); 
                selectExamName(examType,session);
                selectZone(session);
            },
            error:function()
            {
                alert("We are unable to Process.Please contact Support");
            }
        });
    }
    $('#btnReset').click(function(){
        $('#cmbExamtype').selectize()[0].selectize.destroy();
    })
```

Here I am adding value to select field. My requirement is when user will click on "Reset" button the field should clear which is not happening in my case and here I am using selectize.js.Please help me to resolve this issue.

Comment: @subra try to use <form> and html button type= reset. you do not need to add extra script to clear the field

Comment: Yes, I am using form. I only gave the select option code.

Comment: then use <button type="reset"> in place of your reset button, it will clear all values in input fields inside form

Comment: I set the type reset but same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try this [documentation](https://github.com/selectize/selectize.js/blob/master/docs/api.md)

```
$('#cmbExamtype')[0].selectize.clear();
```

Comment: I did as per you but this `Uncaught TypeError: $(...).selectize(...)[0].clear is not a function` error is coming.

Comment: try removing [0] index and check your selector is correct by console.log($('#cmbExamtype').selectize())

Comment: I remove [0] and check in console but no where I found the clear option is there.

Comment: Use it and confirm your input id in correct "#cmbExamtype"
$('#cmbExamtype')[0].selectize.clear();

Comment: its `$("#cmbExamtype").selectize()[0].selectize.clear();` and working.

Comment: Its because ur destroying selectize it in ur success function otherwise no need of reinitialization of selectize to make it clear.

Answer (score 0):

If you run the below sample, while the "select" element is set to "volvo", the jQuery code will clear the selection when you hit the "reset" button:

```js
$("#btnReset").click(function() {
  $("#myid option:selected").prop("selected", false);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title></title>
</head>
<body>
 <div>
  <select id="myid">
      <option value="">Select None</option>
      <option value="volvo" selected>Volvo</option>
      <option value="saab">Saab</option>
      <option value="opel">Opel</option>
      <option value="audi">Audi</option>
    </select>
 </div>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-info tooltips" name="btnReset" id="btnReset" title="Reset"><i class="fa fa-filter"></i> Reset</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

as discussed in comments try to use:

```
<form>
 <div class="col-sm-4">
    <select class="form-control selectized" data-live-search="true" name="cmbExamgrp" id="cmbExamgrp" onChange="selectExamType(this.value,'<?=$MY_SESSION_NAME?>')">
    <option value="">Select Exam Group</option>
    <option value="">Test</option>
        </select>
    </div>
<button type="reset" class="btn btn-info tooltips" name="btnReset" id="btnReset" title="Reset"><i class="fa fa-filter"></i> Reset</button>
</form>
```

https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FQZ0TITVYI2C

Comment: where `p` is present means here `$("p").click(function(){
        $(this).hide();
    });` has written and I am not getting it.

Comment: @subra I have not mentioned $("p").click(function(){ $(this).hide(); }); in my answer. I am just using HTML default reset button functionality here